# Console program for testing automation

Tags: automation, mainframe

I want to test how it works to automate tasks in really old teminal systems. Does anyone know of any such system, which will function without needing a mainframe?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean? You're trying to automate a tn3270 session? But you want to do it without connecting to the mainframe? Maybe you can give us an example.

Comment: @Tom Quarendon. Thanks for your comment. The name tn3270 helped me already. Yes I need to be able to interact with tn3270 without connecting to a mainframe. Can I use a windows server or fake a mainframe in some way?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to automate. If you're trying to write some kind of program that does an automated signon and then runs an application and screen-scrapes the output, then you'd need to run against the real application running on a real mainframe. There are mainframe emulators that might help you for development purposes but they require investment in time/money to set up. You can't fake a mainframe tn3270 session by connecting to windows or unix instead.

Comment: @Tom Quarendon. Thanks for that. Do you do you of any other similar-looking console programs, which will work on Windows without a mainframe or lots of setup to emulate a mainframe.

Comment: Really not sure I understand what it is you're trying to do. You can just use plain telnet to a mainframe and get an interactive telnet prompt, and then you can run command line programs in the same way you would if you telnet'd to, say, a UNIX machine. So to automate that would be the same as automating a normal telnet session, just write a text file and pipe it into the windows telnet, or the putty command line. But still, to test it out you'd need the mainframe in order to be able to connect to it and run the script.

Comment: Most mainframe apps are fullscreen tn3270 though which requires more complicated screenscraping, understanding the full-screen tn320 command streams in order to pick out information from certain locations on screen etc.

Comment: @Tom Quarendon. Thanks to you I solved this using telnet connecting to a ported version of netcat found at http://www.downloadnetcat.com/. It workes exactly as I want. I would like to accept an answer from you.

Comment: Netcat looks very useful. I'll grab a copy myself as I'm needing to do a bit of this kind of thing at the moment anyhow (automating and screenscraping a mainframe telnet/tn3270 connection)

Comment: @Tom Quarendon. If you need screenscraping from the following program, then I have some tools to help you: http://asgard.kent.edu/largesys/Download.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought about this long and hard, I suggest using [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net) for this :-)